# Jquery/Php returning processing status with Ajax POST

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, response

I'm working on a page to process Excel data.

Currently I have an index page where I once submit JSON data (filename, selected columns, worksheet,..) via $.ajax POST to a PHP page for processing (iterate every row with posted selection). But I would like to have some progress response from the processing page. Because now, it just submits and processes everything in the background without knowing if it's done or not.

Is there some kind of way to:

1. Redirect to the processing page, along with the JSON POST data, instead of an ajax post?

OR

2. Return multiple JSON responses from one PHP page (like started, stopped,..) and fetch those responses in the same $.ajax success function? Add some kind of check function like

IF last response-line == started, show image

..after a while (keep checking json response..),

IF last response-line == finished, hide image?

I couldn't use the form submit action, because I'm sending a full JSON string instead of seperate input values.

Am I overlooking something here or is this just not possible (with my way of processing)?

Comment: How does a loader sound?

Comment: I thought about that, but if it's an excel file with 10k records, it would be nice to see on which row he's currently at instead of 10min loading?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `ajax` calls to a different `PHP` file that gets the progress from a session. I also did this once and I did it like this:

**Javascript**

```
function getProgress(){
    //console.log("progress called");
    $.get( "getprogress.php", function( data ) {
        //console.log(data);
        var p = data.progress;

        if (p!=100){
            //set your progressbar here
        }

    }, "json");
}
```

And in the function where you start the job you just set a `timeout`

```
timeout = setInterval('getProgress()', 1000);
```

**Getprogress.php**

```
ob_start();
session_start();
session_write_close();
$output = array();
$output['progress'] = $_SESSION['progress'];
echo json_encode($output);
```

In your `PHP` file where you do the actual work, you need to set the progress like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['progress'] = $progress;
session_write_close();
```

Remember to use `session_write_close()` because the session can only be open in one process at a time.

Comment: Genius! I'll take a look at this and give it a shot! Thanks (Probably not the most efficient way, but hey..)

Comment: No problem, hope it works for you, I searched a lot at that time and I also believe its not the most efficient way but could not find anything better :)